# Ill-conditioned matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inverse matrices are close iff matrices are close](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76357/inverse-matrices-are-close-iff-matrices-are-close)

Consider this problem:

**$Ax = b$**

I want to solve it/find x and the matrix A is ill-conditioned. Why is the fact "A is ill-conditioned" a "bad" thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if one knows the coefficients of $A$ only up to a given precision, a small variation in them will cause a huge variation in the coefficients of $A^{-1}$, hence, presumably, in the solution $x=A^{-1}b$. Alternatively, even if $A^{-1}$ is known with an absolute precision, if one knows the coefficients of $b$ only up to a given precision, a small variation in them will cause a notable variation in the coefficients of the solution $x=A^{-1}b$ since some coefficients of $A^{-1}$ are large. In real life, both effects are often conspiring. See the definition of the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) of a matrix.

Comment: Do you plan to ask over and over [the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76357/6179) here?

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is ill-conditioned if the condition number is too large .

Condition number is the ratio C of the largest to smallest singular value in the singular value decomposition of a matrix.

The base-b logarithm of C is an estimate of how many base-b digits are lost in solving a linear system with that matrix. In other words, it estimates worst-case loss of precision.